# forEach loop Java 8 for Map entry set

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to convert old conventional for each loop till java7 to java8's for each loop for a map entry set but I'm getting an error.
Here's the code I'm trying to convert:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Here's the changes I have done:

```
map.forEach( Map.Entry<String, String> entry -> {
       System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());

   });
```

I tried doing this as well :

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry;
   map.forEach(entry -> {
       System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());

   });
```

But still facing error. The error I'm getting for this is :
Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method `accept(String, String)`

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Read [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-): `Map<K, V>.forEach()` expects a `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V>` as argument, and the signature of the `BiConsumer<T, U>` abstract method is `accept(T t, U u)`.

So you should pass it a lambda expression that takes two inputs as argument: the key and the value:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value : " + value);
});
```

Your code would work if you called forEach() on the entry set of the map, not on the map itself:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
});
```

Comment: Great. Now working both. But which one is a better way? In which case performance would be better? @JBNizet

Comment: The second version forces a `Map.Entry` instance to be created for each entry; the first one gives you key and value with no instantiation. Therefore `Map.Entry` is a middleman and you can avoid that using the first version.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: for most `Map` implementations, the `Map.Entry` instances already exist prior to the iteration and don’t need to be created. Still, not having to deal with `Map.Entry` in the action is a win on readability and has a slight potential for better performance as no additional method invocations are required to retrieve the key and value.

Comment: @Holger I'll stress your tacit implication: for most, _but not all_, `Map` implementations that is true, `ConcurrentHashMap` being an important counterexample.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: but when iterating over an entire `ConcurrentHashMap`, temporary entry instances are the last thing to worry about. Nevertheless, we agree on preferring `map.forEach((key, value) -> …);` anyway…

Answer (score 16):

Maybe the best way to answer the questions like "which version is faster and which one shall I use?" is to look to the source code:

*map.forEach()* - from Map.java

```
default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        try {
            k = entry.getKey();
            v = entry.getValue();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ise) {
            // this usually means the entry is no longer in the map.
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException(ise);
        }
        action.accept(k, v);
    }
}
```

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

*map.entrySet().forEach()* - from Iterable.java

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

This immediately reveals that *map.forEach()* is also using *Map.Entry* internally. So I would not expect any performance benefit in using *map.forEach()* over the *map.entrySet().forEach()*. So in your case the answer really depends on your personal taste :)

For the complete list of differences please refer to the provided javadoc links. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code for your requirement

```
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Item : " + k + " Count : " + v));
```

Comment: This answer is identical to _part of_ the answer provided by JB Nizet 2 years earlier and provides no additional, useful information.

Answer (score 2):

```
String ss = "Pawan kavita kiyansh Patidar Patidar";
    StringBuilder ress = new StringBuilder();
    
    Map<Character, Integer> fre = ss.chars().boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->Character.valueOf((char) k.intValue()),k->1,Integer::sum));
    
      //fre.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v)));
    
    fre.entrySet().forEach(e ->{
            //System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
            //ress.append(String.valueOf(e.getKey())+e.getValue());
        }); 

    fre.forEach((k,v)->{
        //System.out.println("Item : " + k + " Count : " + v);
        ress.append(String.valueOf(k)+String.valueOf(v));
    });
    
    System.out.println(ress.toString());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the tree best ways to do it
1.Iterate with entry set

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
}
```

2. Lambdas
   map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v)));

3 stream
map.entrySet().stream()
.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()));

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer,String> result=new  HashMap<Integer, String>();

result.put(1, "Motorbike");
result.put(2, "Car");
result.put(3, "Jeep");

result.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println(key+ "  "+value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap();

 hm.put("A",1);
 hm.put("B",2);
 hm.put("C",3);
 hm.put("D",4);

 hm.forEach((key,value)->{
     System.out.println("Key: "+key + " value: "+value);
 });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. This will help others adapt your answer to their own needs. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22357648).

Answer (score 0):

#### Stream API

```
public void iterateStreamAPI(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":"e.getValue()));
}
```